# Making a column in Date time with Minutes:Seconds

Tags: python, date, time

I'm having trouble making column into a date time column when I have a column with Minutes and Seconds (example, 210:39:00  ,29:23:00) I have no interest in converting into hours, as it would make very little sense to do so within the context of the purpose of the code. Everything I have found is converting the minutes into hours, Id like to keep a format with just minutes and seconds. From the example "210:39:00" the first number is total minutes, the second number is seconds, the last number is nano seconds. it is a string currently; I would convert to a datetime column with the format %M;%S:%f. I have found no way to do this without transforming the first number which is minutes to hours. I would like to keep total minutes and seconds

Comment: A date of 06/12/2021 should equal to what in minutes and seconds ?

Comment: I can't find any question or problem to be solved!

Comment: please write more about your problem and be clear

Comment: from the example "210:39:00" the first number is total minutes, the second number is seconds, the last number is nano seconds. it is a string currently; I would convert to a datetime column with the format %M;%S:%f. I have found no way to do this without transforming the first number which is minutes to hours. I would like to keep total minutes and seconds

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to store this in a Datetime in the DB then this isn't really a feature of this type. I would suggest either storing a minutes and seconds column as an int or maybe storing total seconds, then in your code doing the maths to create whatever you are displaying